# How do I load files stored in IndexedDB in Unity3D WebGL player?

Tags: file-io, unity-game-engine

I have a game where I wish to save instances of my custom serializable class `Car` so that the player can reuse them later, and in future sessions.
The `Car`class has the following method `Save` which I use to do just that.

```
/// <summary>
/// Serialize and store this instance on the disk.
/// </summary>
public void Save(){
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath+"/car_"+id+".dat", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    formatter.Serialize(fileStream, this);
    fileStream.Close();

    #if UNITY_WEBGL
    // Flush the stream in web player
    Application.ExternalCall("syncfs", false);
    #endif
}
```

As you can see I make an external call to `syncfs`in order to flush the stream to disk. The `syncfs` function is defined as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function syncfs (populate) {
    FS.syncfs(populate, function(err){
        // Callback
    });
}
```

This seems to work as shown in the following image where I have stored two `Car` instances with ids 4 and 5.

[image: Data stored in IndexDB in WebGL player]

The problem is that I cannot seem to load them again. They are loaded using the following method `Load(int id)`

```
/// <summary>
/// Load and deserialize the car with the specified id if it exists.
/// Returns null if it does not exist.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The identifier of the car to load.</param>
public static Car Load(int id){
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath+"/car_"+id+".dat")){
        System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Application.persistentDataPath+"/car_"+id+".dat");
        Car car = (Car) formatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
        return car;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works in the editor, and .NET File I/O should work for WebGL builds.[(2)](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/webgl-filesystem.294358)